# Electrocution Risk in Swimming Pool

Tags: safety, electrocution

Have what I'm sure will seem like a strange question but it is important so if someone could help I would appreciate it. Have a son who is developmentally disabled and he has a thing for water hoses in pools or hot tubs. A picture of him is attached.

So the hose is fine sometimes but in winter it doesn't work and it also causes  problems in other seasons I won't go into. My question is whether it would be safe to use a battery powered submersible pump to operate a hose and pump the water in the tub or pool?

My reasoning is that it recycles the water rather than wastes it and it will make for more comfortable experience as well. Obviously I would not do it if it is dangerous so I know I won't use an electrical pump as there is a one in a million chance something could go wrong.

So electric is out but I can't say I've ever heard of someone being electrocuted by a battery. Would a battery powered submersible pump be safe?
 [image: Picture of Son in Hot Tub With Hose]

Comment: what is the battery voltage?

Comment: Why do you need a submersible pump? Just use a regular pump located well away from the hot tub

Comment: can you hollow a cork to make an adapter to plug the hose into a hotub jet? (i did that as a lad). some pools have a sidewall pump outlet already, used to connect cleaning machines. if not, don't worry about a 12v pump, all it can do is break down, not kill.

Comment: I voted to close this as off-topic because the question is clearly about the use of electronics, not design.

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of mains ac powered submersible pumps (using proper rubberized cable) and, if I thought for one second it would kill my prize koi carp (many of them I might add), I would be very worried. Added to this is the need to add RCDs (or GFCIs in the US) - the instant there is a hint of an insulation  breakdown the RCD (GFCI) will trip the power.

I might add that I have allowed my son to swim in my pool and did not worry.

So no, I don't see an electrocution risk from an ac powered submersible pump and batteries are going to be no worse.

Answer (score 0):

A 12v pump will work fine, but you will need to charge the battery. Where do you fit it - a submersible one won't look good cables etc hitting it with feet...

Why not consider the mains powered pump that is used for the jacuzzi bubbles - isolated, meets the specs for safety and can be fitted underneath with a fitting through the tub wall just like the jets already there . You should be able to find a surface mount connector suitable.